# Why is my main react page just showing the navbar and the footer?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

when opening the page with "npm run dev" I want the home page to be the first one to show, instead I get a page showing only the footer and the navbar which are the components i put inside the layaout cause i want them to be in the rest of other views/links, but there's nothing in between these 2 elements in the very first page to appear when the page opens which makes it looks super weird and janky and I don't know how to fix this

I know I messed up setting the router links somewhere but I'm too new to React and I don't know what I did, please I appreciate any help!

the code from my routes looks like this:

```
import {Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "../../views/Home";
import Menu from "../../views/Menu";
import ContactForm from "../../views/ContactForm";
import Layout from "../layout/Layout"



const AppRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Layout/>}>
                <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>}/>
                <Route path="/menu" element={<Menu/>}/>
                <Route path="/contacto" element={<ContactForm/>}/>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AppRoutes
```

and my layaout like this:

```
import Navigation from "../routes/navigation/Navigation"
import Footer from "../Footer"
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom"

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <Navigation/>
        <Outlet />
        <Footer/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

and this is the page: restaurante-j1mh.vercel.app/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`index`** prop in `Route` component to render like default child route.

Index routes render into their parent's Outlet at their parent's URL by default.

```
const AppRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Layout/>}>
                <Route index path="/home" element={<Home/>}/>
                <Route path="/menu" element={<Menu/>}/>
                <Route path="/contacto" element={<ContactForm/>}/>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </div>
  )
```